# Конфликт Javascript и символа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть такова. На страницу загружается контент, где присутствует знак *₽*. Контент скрыт `display:none`. При клике на определенный элемент, скрытый контент отображается средствами jQuery в блоке `($('.content').html(content);)`.

Проблема в том, что сначала в блок загружается текст контента до вхождения знака *₽*, потом весь текст со страницы секунды на 2 исчезает, и появляется уже весь контент.

Что это может быть?

При удалении этого знака из текста все отображается без глюков, проблема точно в этом знаке.

Comment: как вариант используй вместо знака &#8381;

Comment: Без воспроизводимого примера что-то внятное ответить не получится. Вот у вас в тексте вопроса есть этот символ - но эта страница вполне нормально грузится, значит дело не в символе, а в чем-то другом

Comment: А еще, как вариант, можно по клику не контент загружать, а свойство `display` менять.

Comment: приведите минимально вопроизводимый фрагмент кода